# Need help with repairing a door

Tags: doors

Someone must have kicked in the door of the house I just bought. The door faces the sun all day long. It is really unsightly and doesn't seat well. I think this is a bit out of my hands to repair. My questions are:

1. How much work will need to be done where the strike plates are?
2. Is the door itself done for and should I buy a new door?
3. Does the door need to be adjusted to make it so light doesn't come through? I have put new weather stripping in place but the light is still coming through where the door connects to the wall.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You are ready for a new door and door jamb.

Comment: +1 The door itself, the jamb on the strike side, the stops around the door and the jamb on the hinge side all seem compromised. While it *might* be possible to fix everything, the amount of work involved by a skilled craftsperson would probably cost more than a new setup, and it would be difficult to get it all looking as good as a new unit.

Comment: I could not have put either answer or comment better myself